# how to get number of subscribers using 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

I'm currently working on a java application that can get me the number of subscribers of each mobile network operator.
To do so, I've created a table with all the operators I called it indicatifs and it contains the 3 rows: country, operator and mobile_prefix.
My second table, called subs contains two rows: mobile_prefix and number of subscribers
What query should I use in order to get something like this:

```
Operator   Country   Number of Subscribers
SFR        France    20000
T-Mobile   USA       10250
Telia      Sweden    5248
```

..
any kind of help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
select a.country, a.operator, count(*) as subscriber
from indicatifs a
left join subs b
 on a.mobile_prefix = b.mobile_prefix
group by a.operator, a.country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.operator,a.country,b.number_of_subscriber from table1 a left join table2 b on a.mobile_prefix = b.mobile_prefix;
```

Is this what you want ??
pls check

Comment: So I shoud use mobile_prefix as a foreign key?

Comment: since mobile_prefix column is present in both the tables, i thought it would be relating to records in another table.

Answer (score 0):

This query requires a `join` and `group by`.  You want to use a `left join` -- assuming you want all operators, even those with no subscribers:

```
select i.operator, i.country, count(s.mobile_prefix) as numsubs
from indicatifs i left join
     subs s
     on i.mobile_prefix = s.mobile_prefix
group by i.operator, i.country
order by numsubs desc;
```